# Mathematical notation or Pseudocode?

Tags: math, pseudocode, notation

At this moment I am concerned about which is the best way to explain an algorithm intuitively.

I have try to read some pseudocode an wow it may be complex for some cases (specially for math applications even more than the formulas itself or pure code like in PHP, C++ or Py). I have thought how about describe algorithms from mathematical notation in a way such that a mathematician could understand it and a web developer too.

Do you think it is a good idea ? (IF all the grammars and structure, symbols and modelings of it will be well explained and it is compact)

Example:
[Binary Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfkyK.png)

It even could help to simplify algorithm complexity if a mathematical analysis is done (I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the algorithm. For me, I know I would have never gotten the concept of trees if I didn't get a visual drawing. Also the concept of nodes, while a drawing is good, actually seeing the data structure written down is better for that case.

It's student to student basis. I personally see that example of the Binary Search as the worst type of example but am sure some math individual would maybe understand that better.